# Upgrading Android Support Library to use Android M Permissions model

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I'm new to Android working on a project that supports API 8 and above. It's a gradle project using Android Support Library version 18.0.0. In order to support the new permissions model that uses ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback interface,  ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() etc., I am trying to use latest version com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 instead of the current version com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0, but when I change the version my app crashes saying "Unfortunately,  has stopped" dialog with an exception related to TabHost which is used in one of the fragments in the app. Please help.

> E/AndroidRuntime(15040): Process:
>   com.example.publisher.test.adaptiveId, PID: 15040
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.publisher.test.adaptiveId/com.example.sdk.test.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TabHost.setup()' on a null object reference
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
>   Method) E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TabHost.setup()'
>   on a null object reference E/AndroidRuntime(15040):   at
>   com.example.sdk.test.MainActivity.setupTabs(MainActivity.java:166)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   com.example.sdk.test.TabsFragment.onActivityCreated(TabsFragment.java:47)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1970)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1051)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1189)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2001)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:165)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:507)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15040):  ... 9 more

Comment: It seems your problem has nothing to do with the fact that you updated the Support library but rather related to the fact that your `TabHost` is null as written here `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TabHost.setup()'`

Comment: You are going to need to look at line 166 of `MainActivity.java`, in your `setupTabs()` method, and determine why your `TabHost` is `null`. We cannot help you with this, as you have not provided a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which in this case would include the source code to the relevant portions of `MainActivity`.

Comment: Turns out that `findViewById()` in the new support library (com.android.support:support-v4:23.+) doesn't **find** the root like it used to be before. Casting the view returned by `inflater.inflate(int resource, ViewGroup vg);` to TabHost fixed my issue.